# Which constructor is called first while passing null in the class having overloaded constructor?

Tags: java, overloading

Below is the java class having 3 overloaded constructors :

```
public class Test {

    public Test(Object i){
        System.out.println("Object invoked");
    }

    public Test(String i){
        System.out.println("String invoked");
    }

    public Test(int k){
        System.out.println("Integer invoked");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Test t = new Test(null);
    }
}
```

If null value is passed while creating the new instance of class, which constructor will be invoked ? What is the reason ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Java always chooses the most *specific* method (or constructor) that would be applicable for the argument you pass. In this case, that's the `String` constructor -- `String` is a subclass of `Object`.

Think about what would happen if you had

```
new Test("some string")
```

*Both* the `Object` and `String` constructors would be applicable here. After all, the argument is both an `Object` and a `String`. *However*, it is clear that the `String` constructor will be invoked because it is more specific than the `Object` constructor and still is applicable given the argument.

`null` is no different; these two constructors are still applicable, and the `String` constructor is still chosen over the `Object` one for the same reason.

Now, if there were two equally "specific" constructors present (e.g. if you had an `Integer` constructor) there would be a compilation error when you call `Test(null)`.

This is outlined in more detail in [JLS §15.12.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2):

> The second step searches the type determined in the previous step for member methods. This step uses the name of the method and the types of the argument expressions to locate methods that are both accessible and applicable, that is, declarations that can be correctly invoked on the given arguments.
>
> There may be more than one such method, in which case the *most specific* one is chosen. The descriptor (signature plus return type) of the most specific method is one used at run time to perform the method dispatch.

The explicit process of determining which method is the most specific is outlined in [JLS §15.12.2.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5).

Comment: But among String and object why String constructor is called ?

Comment: @KshitijJain Because `null` is applicable for both `Object` *and* `String`. `String` is more specific (it is a subclass of object) and so that constructor is invoked. If you want a more in-depth explanation, I'll direct you to the JLS link in the answer.

Comment: @KshitijJain I added a little more explanation. Maybe it'll make it clearer.

Comment: @arshajii your explanation clears it up a lot. I think the confusion is because `null` doesn't resolve to a type; but it helps to think in the other direction - it's possible for a `String` (or an `Object`) to have the value `null`. At least, this is why _I_ thought the code in the OP wouldn't compile.

Comment: i think the question here is , why is String constructor called , is 'null' a String object or System.out.println class has a defined method with null input param passing '' as a String

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: `Test(String)` is invoked.

Why?

When determining which of a set of overloaded methods will be invoked, the Java compiler will attempt to match the most concrete type.  And it will first attempt to match a signature *before* employing autoboxing.  (@arshajii provided a perfect reference into the Java Language Spec on this)

Here, `Object` is the most abstract class in the type system.  `String` subclasses from `Object` and is therefore more specific/concrete.

The logic behind this is that if you are overloading a method with a more specific-typed parameter, you're likely wanting to do more with that object (when you subclass, you typically add methods).  If method signature determination worked the other way (i.e. the more abstractly-typed signature winning; here, `Test(Object)`), then none of the more concrete signatures would ever get called.